# To draw Bizier Curve using Line object coordinates in Blender

Tags: python

I want to draw a bezier curve using the coordinates of the line object on the blender. As a result of proceeding with "AUTO" all of the spline handle, it is not different from the regular line object. I want a softer curve. Below is the script

[image]

[image]

Comment: please...use the text editor to copy/paste code and not an image. thx.

Comment: Hi. Please don't post images or screenshots of your code, console or error messages, instead copy-paste the actual text into your post using proper code tags, so it can be indexed and searched for, and other users trying to help don't have to type it by hand themselves which is error prone and time consuming.